# Azure Devops - missing permission to view azure pipeline releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm getting the following message when trying to view azure pipeline releases: "You do not have permissions to modify this releases pipeline. Changes made will not be saved. Contact your release manager to grant permissions". [Pipeline Release View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM2QE.png)

I have Release Administrators and Project Administrators. Navigation to security shows that I have all the necessary permissions: [Pipelines<Security<My User Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1S6L.png)

Any suggestions how I can solve this issue - to get the permissions needed to edit pipeline releases? My team have tried to remove me from the team and project and then re-add me - but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your permissions on the particular pipeline:

[image]

Comment: It shows that I have all permissions for the particular pipeline. It's quite strange...